# Equivalent to Website Publish for Console/Winforms apps in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, build, publish

I've got a website and a console application which work together.

The Website is published to any of ~10 different servers depending on the publish profile. For production, that's MSDeploy but for Dev/Test/UAT/etc... it's a simple UNC File path copy.

I'd like to be able to publish the CLI as easily (at least to "local" servers). What I want is to click Publish, pick the Profile/Server and have it compile and copy the output in the bin folder to `\\Server\ApplicationName`

I'm aware I could perform the Copy as a Post-Build step but don't *always* want to do the copy and definitely don't always want it to the same place.

The publish options which exist for Console/WinForms apps seem to center around 1-click publishing which isn't what I'm after (I don't want the app phoning home looking for new versions every time, I want to explicitly push a specific version to a specific server).

I'm aware that if the app is running during the attempted publish, there will be problems.

Is this achievable?